# DevExpress cxGrid master detail

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am completely new to DevExpress, and amount of properties and objects just creeps me out.

I have created cxGrid with master detail views. I just cant figure out how to control selecting record within details view. I would like to select specific sub-record programatically.

In case of master view, I can use DataController, but DataController of the details view gives me either -1 or 0 records.

How to access those filtered subrecords of a specific master record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `detail DataController` directly accessible from your `detail view` is sort of a *pattern* for the real detail DataControllers. What you really need is to get a `detail DataController` that holds the `detail records` corresponding to your `master record`.

In order to do this you have to use the `GetDetailDataController` method to get a clone of the detail view *pattern*, which will contain only the `detail records` of the `master record` you are interested in.

```
MyDetailDataController := MasterView.DataController.GetDetailDataController(AMasterRecordIndex, ARelationIndex);
```

The parameters for this call are following:

- `AMasterRecordIndex` specifies the record index of the master.
- `ARelationIndex` specifies the `detail view index`. This is used mostly for cases where a master view has more than one detail view. If you have only one set it to 0.